# unable to read the data from custom Hook in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Here I'm expecting to get the *tags* value from *useTags* Hook, But it is returning undefined. Here is my code.

**App.js**

```
export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [tags] = useTags();
  const clickHandler = () => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(tags));
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => { setData(["java", "javascript"]); }, 3000)
  }, []);
  console.log('[App.js] rendered');
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TagList data={data} />
      <button onClick={clickHandler}>click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**TagList.js**

```
import { memo, useEffect, useState } from "react";
export const useTags = (data) => {
    const [tags, setTags] = useState(data);
    const updateTags = (tags) => {
        setTags(tags);
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        setTags(data);
    }, [JSON.stringify(data)])
    return [
        tags,
        updateTags
    ]
}
const Tag = memo(({ tags, tagRemoveHandler, errIndex = -1 }) => {
    return (
        <div className="taglist-tags">
            {tags.map((tag, index) => (
                <div className={errIndex === index ? "taglist-tag error" : "taglist-tag"} key={tag} >
                    <span className="taglist-tag-text">{tag}</span>
                    <span className="taglist-tag-remove" onClick={() => tagRemoveHandler(tag)} >
                        <span className="icon-close"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
});
export const TagList = ({ data }) => {
    const [tags, updateTags] = useTags(data);
    const [tag, setTag] = useState("");
    const [errIndex, setErrIndex] = useState(-1);
    useEffect(() => {
        let timer;
        if (errIndex != -1) {
            timer = setTimeout(() => {
                setErrIndex(-1);
            }, 3000);
        }
        return () => {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        };
    }, [errIndex]);
    const keyDownListener = (e) => {
        if (e.key === "Enter" || e.code == "Comma") {
            e.preventDefault();
            let index = tags.indexOf(tag);
            if (index > -1) {
                return setErrIndex(index);
            }
            updateTags([...tags, tag]);
            setTag("");
        }
    };
    const changeHandler = (e) => {
        setTag(e.target.value);
    };
    const tagRemoveHandler = (t) => {
        updateTags(() => tags.filter((tag) => tag !== t));
    };
    return (
        <>
            <div style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}>
                <h2>Create tags here.</h2>
                <label>press enter to create a tag</label>
            </div>
            <div className="taglist">
                <Tag
                    tags={tags}
                    tagRemoveHandler={tagRemoveHandler}
                    errIndex={errIndex}
                />
                <textarea
                    className="taglist-input"
                    value={tag}
                    onKeyDown={keyDownListener}
                    onChange={changeHandler}
                />
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

It will create a UI like this.
I want to get the **tags** from **useTags** whenever i click on the button. Unfortunately it is returning undefined.

And also wanted to know the performance of the above code. Expecting positive results.

Thank you for the community support
[image: The end result]

Comment: `tags` starts off equal to whatever the input to `useTags` is, which in your case is `undefined` since you call it as `useTags()`. That will *always* be true on the first render. And since you don't even use the setter function that's also returned by `useTags`, then it will never change either. I have no idea what your intention is but this hook seems like a really simple and unnecessary wrapper for `useState` anyway.

Comment: looking again, it appears that you're getting confused between a `useState` and your `useTags` wrapper. Everything you're actually doing inside `app` refers to the `data` that you're using the state hook for - `tags` isn't even used except in the click handler...

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, pass the data prop to the useTags hook.
Code -

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [tags] = useTags(data); // Pass the 'data' prop to the hook
  const clickHandler = () => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(tags));
  }
```